# How to send stringlist in email and change alignment and format of text

Tags: delphi

I have created a leavers form for a user to enter details into edit boxes and combo boxes. I then created a button which will send an email containing all the values from the details entered into said edit and combo boxes. I done this by creating a string list and then assigning it to the mailitem.body. All works fine but i would like a way to make the body of the email look better. Either by changing formatting, font size of text etc or at the very least being able to align left and align center my text within the body of the email.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const    
  olMailItem = 0;    
var
  Outlook : OLEVariant;
  MailItem : Variant;
  MailInspector : Variant;
  stringlist : TStringlist;
  tab : Char;
begin;
  try    
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except    
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');    
  end;

  try    
    Stringlist := TStringList.Create;    
    MailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem) ;    
    MailItem.Subject := 'Leavers form';    
    MailItem.Recipients.Add('*******@hotmail.com');    
    MailItem.CC:='******@googlemail.com';

    Stringlist := TStringList.Create;
    Tab := chr(9);   

    StringList.Add('Hi all,');
    StringList.Add('Please find leavers details below,');
    StringList.Add('Thank you,');
    StringList.Add('');
    StringList.Add('Employee Name:' + tab + edit1.text);
    StringList.Add('Payroll Number:' + tab + edit2.text);
    stringList.Add('Campaign:' + tab + edit3.text);
    stringList.Add('Leave Date:' + tab + edit4.text);
    stringList.Add('probation period:' + tab + Combobox1.text);
    stringList.Add('Reason for leaving:' + tab + Combobox8.text);
    stringList.Add('If other please specify:' + tab + edit7.text);
    stringList.Add('Would you re-employ?:' + tab  + Combobox2.text);
    stringList.Add('If "no" please specify reasons:' + tab  + edit9.text);
    stringList.Add('Has Employee recieved an advance:' + tab + Combobox3.text);
    stringList.Add('payment which needs to be recuped');
    stringList.Add('from their final salay' + tab + edit11.text);
    stringList.Add('Due any payment in lieu of notice?:' + tab  + Combobox4.text);
    stringList.Add('If "yes" please specify weeks to pay e.g 4.25:'+ tab + edit13.text);
    stringList.Add('Holiday Entitlment to date:' + tab + edit14.text);
    stringList.Add('Holiday taken to date:' + tab + edit15.text);
    stringList.Add('Holidays to be paid/deducted:'+ tab  + edit16.text);
    stringList.Add('has employee returned laptop?:' + tab +combobox9.text) ;
    stringList.Add('Has employee returned pass?: ' + tab + Combobox5.text);
    stringList.Add('Has employee returned headset?:' + tab + Combobox6.text);
    stringList.Add('Has employee returned locker key?:' + tab + Combobox7.text);    

    MailItem.Body := stringlist.text ;    
    MailItem.Send;
```

Actual results

```
Hi all, 
Please find leavers details below, 
Thank you, 
Employee Name:  Jeffy Biscuits 
Payroll Number: 123456789 
Campaign:       HR 
Leave Date:     23/12/2018 
probation period:       No 
Reason for leaving:     Dismissal 
If other please specify:        
Would you re-employ?:   No 
If "no" please specify reasons: Poor attendance 
Has Employee recieved an advance:       No 
payment which needs to be recuped 
from their final salay  
Due any payment in lieu of notice?:     No 
If "yes" please specify weeks to pay e.g 4.25:  
Holiday Entitlment to date:     0 
Holiday taken to date:  30 
Holidays to be paid/deducted:   5 
has employee returned laptop?:  N/A 
Has employee returned pass?:    Yes 
Has employee returned headset?: Yes 
Has employee returned locker key?:
```

Expected

```
Hi all, 
Please find leavers details below, 
Thank you, 
Employee Name:                                  Jeffy Biscuits 
Payroll Number:                                 123456789 
Campaign:                                       HR 
Leave Date:                                     23/12/2018 
probation period:                               No 
Reason for leaving:                             Dismissal 
If other please specify:        
Would you re-employ?:                           No 
If "no" please specify reasons:                 Poor attendance 
Has Employee recieved an advance:               No 
payment which needs to be recuped 
from their final salay  
Due any payment in lieu of notice?:             No 
If "yes" please specify weeks to pay e.g 4.25:  
Holiday Entitlment to date:                     0 
Holiday taken to date:                          30 
Holidays to be paid/deducted:                   5 
has employee returned laptop?:                  N/A 
Has employee returned pass?:                    Yes 
Has employee returned headset?:                 Yes 
Has employee returned locker key?:
```

( I know the spacing between question need fixed but looking for the the text aliment and hopefully font etc )

Comment: If not plain text, your most sensible options are either RTF or HTML.  Either will allow you to define the layout and style of the email.

Comment: You can do it in plain text as well, but not using the tab character. Basically you'd have to check what the longest string before the tab characters is, and fill out every string with spaces to that length. But then you still depend on the display of the mail client. If it doesn't use a mono-spaced font, your layout will fail. HTML is the better option, and pretty much every client supports it.

Comment: I had tried by adding the string spaces but it ended up everywhere. The tab was just experimenting and does much the same as adding a couple of spaces in the string. I'm not sure what i am doing with the html but will need to research a bit more

Comment: "A couple of spaces" needs to be the right number of spaces. What the right number is varies per line. Btw, are those real e-mail addresses? You might want to remove those.

Comment: "A couple of spaces" was referring to the tab function i had added that was the equivalent of adding a couple of spaces to the string. Yes each line is different in length clearly but the spacing in Delphi differs from what is being output in the email. i would of thought there was some way to format stringlists to align them left and centre. Can i output RTF  without it having to have something on the form? I Can get html working in as far as i can send one line but i'm not sure how to add additional lines and formatting etc

Comment: If I would send the data as html, I would use `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. Take a look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: @TomBrunberg do you have an example of getting html into the mailtitem.body?

Comment: @jeffybiscuits HTML is itself simply plain text containing formatting tags, so you add it to the `MailItem.Body` the same way you add any kind of text. You just need to make sure to set the `MailItem.BodyFormat` to `olFormatHTML` so the recipient knows the email contains HTML and not plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have initialized the `MailItem` properties populate the `StringList: TStringList` to hold your `html` content:

```
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  ...

    StringList.Add('<html>');
    StringList.Add('<head>');
    StringList.Add('<style>');
    StringList.Add('table, th, td {');
    //StringList.Add('  border: 1px solid black;');
    StringList.Add('}');
    StringList.Add('</style>');
    StringList.Add('</head>');
```

then start with the `<body>`:

and with the monthly report and salutation

```
...
    StringList.Add('<body>');
    StringList.Add('<table>');
    StringList.Add('  <tr>');
    StringList.Add('    <th>Month</th>');
    StringList.Add('    <th>Savings</th>');
    StringList.Add('  </tr>');
    StringList.Add('  <tr>');
    StringList.Add('    <td>January</td>');
    StringList.Add('    <td>$100</td>');
    StringList.Add('  </tr>');
    StringList.Add('  <tr>');
    StringList.Add('    <td>February</td>');
    StringList.Add('    <td>$80</td>');
    StringList.Add('  </tr>');
    StringList.Add('</table>');
    StringList.Add('<p>');
    StringList.Add('<p>');

    StringList.Add('Hi all,<p>');
    StringList.Add('Please find leavers details below,<p>');
    StringList.Add('Thank you,<p>');
    StringList.Add('<p>');
```

the table and end of body and html

```
  ...
    StringList.Add('<table>');
    StringList.Add('<tr><td>Employee Name:</td>'            + '<td>' + edit1.text     + '</td>');
    StringList.Add('<tr><td>Payroll Number:</td>'           + '<td>' + edit2.text     + '</td>');
    StringList.Add('<tr><td>Campaign:</td>'                 + '<td>' + edit3.text     + '</td>');
    StringList.Add('<tr><td>Leave Date:</td>'               + '<td>' + edit4.text     + '</td>');
    StringList.Add('<tr><td>probation period:</td>'         + '<td>' + Combobox1.text + '</td>');
  ... (continues)
  ...
    StringList.Add('</table>');
    StringList.Add('</body>');
    StringList.Add('</html>');
```

Then add `StringList.Text` to `MailItem.Body` and send.

Please note that there's just empty space between the first and second field of each record in my editor. That is only to have better visibility during coding, to spot eventually missing stuff. The space is not needed for the table. The table adjusts itself according to textual content (width of columns can also be explicitly set, look at html docs)

Comment: This works brilliantly! Thanks Tom. although it creates boxes round my email signature as well... trying to work out how to remove that....

Comment: Don't forget to set the `MailItem.BodyFormat` to `olFormatHTML` so the recipient knows the email contains HTML.

Comment: I used the MailItem.htmlBody := StringList.text; command and that seems to work but still having issues with the email signature.  It seems to create a table around the email sig and there is probably a simple way to stop it but havent worked it out yet

Comment: @jeffy I'm not sure I get it, how my answer affects the signature. Could you edit your question with an image of the problem with the email sig. Or if it is unrelated to the usage of html code, please post a new question.

Comment: @jeffy Thanks for the image. First, it seems you have uncommented the line: `//StringList.Add('  border: 1px solid black;');` because the table shows the lines. That's ok if that is what you want. From the image I also conclude that you  enclosed the signature with the `<tr><td></td>` tags. That you should not do if you do not want to have them in a table. Write the signature after the `</table>` (end of table) tag. You can also use two tables like: `<table>leavers data</table>` with or without lines and `<table>signature</table>` with its own line setting.

Comment: Ok, here is what i have as you had previously stated

Comment: StringList.Add('<html>');
    StringList.Add('<head>');
    StringList.Add('<style>');
    StringList.Add('table, th, td {');
    StringList.Add('  border: 1px solid black;');
    StringList.Add('}');
    StringList.Add('</style>');
    StringList.Add('</head>');

Comment: I havent got any <tr><td></td> tags on the signature. the Signature is auto pulled from office 365. So when composing a standard email it doesnt show the signature . its added after sending. So the code is adding a table to the whole body. i can close the table and add text at the bottom but it still creates a table round the email signature. i guess maybe because of the way the signature is applied i might not be able to change that

Comment: @jeffy That *the Signature is auto pulled from office 365* is beyond my experience. Don't you have a marker or something in your mail template to indicate where the signature is placed? But just of curiosity, if you out comment the `StringList.Add('  border: 1px solid black;');` (as in the first block of my answer), what is the result regarding the signature?

Comment: @Tom if you comment out StringList.Add(' border: 1px solid black;'); it removes the table and keeps the text nice and aligned, which is what i was looking for in the first place. so yeah that works.... i just happen to really like the table now and would ideally like to keep it in but i guess i am splitting hairs now

Comment: @jeffy Ok, sometimes we have to choose between partly bad and really bad :) But if you removed the table lines, did it also remove the lines from the signature? And what about my question regarding a marker for the signature?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it removed from both table and signature so that is great! I havent looked at the marker yet. Will update once i have